# Telethon. Поиск сообщений от конкретного пользователя в чате

Tags: telegram, telethon

Всем доброго дня! Как можно в библиотеке Telethon сделать поиск сообщений в чате telegram от конкретного пользователя?
В стандартном клиенте Telegram есть такой функционал

Comment: Сохранять все сообщения у себя(на стороне сервера) и делать по ним поиск любым удобным способом, например используя [СУБД](https://habr.com/ru/post/579248/)

Comment: Я так понимаю нет вариантов, кроме скачивания всего чата?

Comment: В стандартном клиенте поиск работает именно так :)

Comment: Спасибо большое!